# Merge two arrays together in JS

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and I want to add both. Is it possible to get this:

```
var frist = {
    "2162018": [
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529570651.113
        },
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529570827.709
        }
    ]
};
var second = {
    "2362018": [
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529574243.613
        }
    ]
};
//and i want my final data array like this 
var final_data = {
    "2162018": [
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529570651.113
        },
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529570827.709
        }
    ],
    "2362018": [
        {
            st_id: "18ds1",
            status: "A",
            today_milli: 1529574243.613
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var frist =  
{ '2162018': 
    [
      { st_id: '18ds1', status: 'A', today_milli: 1529570651.113 },
      { st_id: '18ds1', status: 'A', today_milli: 1529570827.709 }
    ]
 }

 var second = 
 { '2362018': 
   [ 
     { st_id: '18ds1', status: 'A', today_milli: 1529574243.613 } 
   ] 
 }

let final_data = {...frist,...second}
console.log(final_data)
```

Yes you can simply using spread syntax to combine and construct new object

Comment: thanks bro it works. this problem wasted my all day :-(

Comment: You can mark it as answer as reference for other people who face the similar problem.